# When using %matplotlib notebook, is there a way for plots to become interactive within a loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, interactive

I'm using a Jupyter notebook with interactive plots using `%matplotlib notebook`. The goal is to loop through a bunch of pictures, and for each image I'll get some information about the image and enter it. It'll then clear the plot and I'll move on to the next.

The problem is that it seems the plots become interactive once the cell has finished its computation. Is there a way of making a plot become interactive within a loop?